# Reading file by words in Windows Batch and Bash

Tags: windows, bash, cmd

I need to print all words with number of repeats of each word from a file. But i Can't understand how to read file by words in Win CMD and Bash. How can I do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Windows Batch Only**

This will enumerate every word in a file and display the word and its count.

**Limitations**

1. Batch Line Length Limit of [8191](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/830473) (Windows XP+). [2047](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/830473) for older OS.

**Script**

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableExtensions DisableDelayedExpansion
for /f "delims=" %%A in (file.txt) do (
    set "_=%%A"
    call :Expand_
)

:: Display the Word and Count
rem set word:
for /f "tokens=2,3 delims=:=" %%X in ('set word:') do echo %%X = %%Y
goto End


:Expand_
:: Clean Special Characters
set "_=%_:"=%"
set "_=%_:^=%"
set "_=%_:<=%"
set "_=%_:>=%"
set "_=%_:&=%"
set "_=%_:|=%"
:: Replace Whitespace
set "_=%_:  =%"
:: Remove Plurals
rem set "_=%_:'s=%"
:: Clean Punctuation
:WordLoop
for /f "tokens=1,* delims=`~!@#$%%*()-_+=\[]{};:/?., " %%X in ("%_%") do (
    set ".=%%X"
    call :Expand.
    set "_=%%Y"
)
if defined _ goto WordLoop
goto :eof

:Expand.
:: Count the Words
if defined word:%.% (
    set /a "word:%.%+=1"
) else (
    set "word:%.%=1"
)
goto :eof


:End
endlocal
```

Comment: I expected just reading files, but you're so kind! Thank you  very much!

Comment: It was my pleasure.  It was not much work since all it required was a few modifications from scripts that I have already written. **`:)`**